# How do you describe an anomaly in the car body! deformation? Sunken?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Suppose you had a very slight car accident and a point of the car's door looks as if it's pushed in, something like this

[image]

However, without any scratches, just a simple anomaly that can be easily fixed. How do you describe the door?

I came up with:

> 1. The car's left door is now a bit deformed
> 2. The car's left door is now a bit pushed-in
> 3. The car's door looks concave

I am not sure about any of these sentence. Would you help with this?

---

Photo Reference: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/fiat-punto-door-dent (The owner of this picture can ask me to delete his/her photo)

Comment: The page you linked uses the word "dent"...

Comment: Your three example sentences are fine.  Except you'd still likely have to follow up to clarify the damage with " ...there's a **dent** in the side"

Comment: Description: in need of a tool known as a dent puller.

Comment: The damage in the photo, even if we imagine the scrapes as not present, is a little worse than a *dent*. I'd say the door was badly dented and a little **bent out of shape** or **deformed**.

Comment: Nah, it's a dent. If it were the width of the door, you might say it were ***caved in***.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

My first thought was “dent”:

> [dent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dent)
>   a small, hollow mark in the surface of something caused by pressure or being hit:
>   She ran into my car and put a dent in it.
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

Briefly, “deformation” suggests to me a manufacturer’s error, not a dent.

“Pushed in” seems okay to me, but that’s somewhat broad, or not as specific as “dent”.

“Concave” sounds like a technical observation and not really like damage from an accident.

Answer (score 22):

It's called a dent (noun). The door is dented (adj). He had a small accident and dented (verb) the door.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dent

Answer (score 17):

> The car's door is [dented](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dented).
>
> The door has a large [dent](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dent_1).

A dent can be as small as a coin-sized [ding](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ding) or [dimple](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dimple).

Smashing an entire side of a sheet-metal object can cause very large dents, or [crumple](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crumple) the object.

Answer (score 14):

If the dent is small, it's known as a [ding](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ding) <- see ding2

The difference between a ding and a dent is an informal one:

- http://bigskycol.com/is-it-a-ding-or-a-dent/
- http://www.suburbanautobody.com/Blog/entryid/63/what-is-the-difference-between-a-ding-and-a-dent

but relates to size, whether the paint is scratched etc.

Comment: I've had a few arguments over dent/ding and now I can add this (size based) info to my rebuttals :)